# First $2^n$ tosses in coin toss

Tags: probability

I have a question about coin toss.
                       We will call an infinite sequence of coin tosses a good sequence if at least one of this statements is true for it:

statement 1: we got H on the first 2^1 tosses
statement 2: We got HH on the first 2^2 tosses
statement 3: We got HHH on the first 2^3 tosses
statement 4: We got HHHH on the first 2^4 tosses
.
.
.
statement n: We got HH...H (n times H) on the first 2^n tosses
.
.
.
(note that H means heads and T means tails)

My question is: Is every sequence of coin tosses a good sequence?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Obviously not. Consider a sequence with only $T$. Or $TTHTHTHTH\ldots$ or so many others.

Comment: but the probability that I get H is 0.5, and not 0 so an infinite sequence with only T is not possible. For the same reason, your second example is not possible because the probability that I get HH is 0.25 and not 0.

Comment: Is your question "Is the probability of a good sequence equal to 1" because that is not the same as "every sequence is a good sequence".

Comment: no. my question is if any sequence is a good sequence